# How to find the sum of a row where there are numbers in another row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The cell `B3` is found by `sum(C3:AE3)/sum($C$2:$AE$2)`. `sum($C$2:$AE$2)` gives the total of all the tests.

But I am not sure how to find the sum of the test where there are numbers.

For Scott, I need to find `sum(C4:AE4)/sum of 70 and 55)` since he took Test 2 and 4.

For Tim,  `sum(C5:AE5)/(sum of 60, 65 and 55`, since he took the Test 1, 3 and 4.

How can I detect the cells where there are no numbers and not including in the total sum.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,MMULT(C3:AE*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C:AE))^0)/SUM(C2:AE2)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I like this one because it uses ARRAYFORMULA. Thanks. I just do not know what's going on, though. What is A3:A="" doing?

Comment: it means: If A3:A range is empty do empty otherwise do MMULT

Answer (score 1):

Try with this for Scott:

```
 =sum(C4:AE4) / arrayformula(sum(if(isblank(C4:AE4),0,$C$2:$AE$2)))
```